# How can zsh handle multiple redirections?

Tags: c, file, operating-system, sh, zsh

For example, in `zsh`, you can do:

```
% cat < file1 < file2
```

and you will see both. How can `zsh` do this while being transparent to the `cat` program?

The `cat` program reads from `STDIN_FILENO` and prints to `STDOUT_FILENO` on a POSIX system, so how can that one file descriptor point to multiple open file descriptions? In `sh`, only the last redirection (rightmost) is performed.

Comment: Even with `cat < file1`, the redirection is not visible to `cat`. It has no idea that its standard input is a file named `file1`, only that it can, in fact, read from standard input. The shell is free to define *how* that happens, and in particular it is not bound by any rule that says each `<` operator must produce exactly one file descriptor.

Comment: @user129393192 You asked about the downvotes.  I don't know (I didn't vote), but I suspect someone felt this wasn't really a programming question — it's arguably more appropriate for Server Fault or Unix&Linux.  But it's an interesting question, and I thank you for posting it, because I learned something from the question and its answers.

Comment: You say "In sh, only the last redirection (rightmost) is performed".  When I try "`cat <missing <present`", the shell says "`-bash: missing: No such file or directory`" (because there is no such file in my current directory).  IOW, it does try to open the first file (and fails if it can't), but when it processes the second input redirection, it closes the first and redirects from the second.  It's simple to implement.  Extending the experiment: `echo One > One; echo Two > Two; cat <One <Two` produces just `Two` in Bash.

Comment: This could be interpreted as a programming question as how this could be reproduced in C, given the [tag:c] tag.

Comment: That was actually what I was hoping for @user16217248

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : bash processes the redirections from left to right. Therefore it needs to open _missing_, even if the filedescriptor is then reopened for _present_.

Answer (score 5):

`zsh` calls this "multios", and input redirection works by using a child process to read the files in order and forward their contents to a pipe connected to the standard input of the process being redirected to.

From [the documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios):

> If the user tries to open a file descriptor for reading more than once, the shell opens the file descriptor as a pipe to a process that copies all the specified inputs to its output in the order specified, provided the `MULTIOS` option is set.

(A similar approach is taken with multiple output redirections of the same descriptor.)

So `something <file1 <file2` is roughly equivalent to `cat file1 file2 | something`, though there are some subtle differences about *when* the input files are opened - all at once vs sequentially with `cat`.

Comment: Does the output variant mean that `cat /etc/passwd > copy.1 > copy.2` creates to identical copies of `/etc/passwd` called `copy.1` and `copy.2`? —— And, answering my question before hitting send, the answer is "Yes, by default (on macOS Monterey), the output is two identical files". This renders the `tee` command largely unnecessary except for reasons of portability or when the output also needs to travel further down a pipeline.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler something like `cat file | cat > copy | cat` still sends output to the screen, and to the last `cat`. MacOS Ventura, zsh. This seems to be a different feature than the one this question was originally about though.

Comment: @user129393192: reading the cross-referenced documentation, I gathered that , so `tee` is redundant in Zsh.  There's a moderate chance that with process substitution, even the `pee` command or its equivalents is redundant too.

Answer (score 3):

The program is provided a handle to a pipe, rather than a handle to a plain file.<sup>[1]</sup> `zsh` reads the files and writes them to the pipe.

In other words,

```
prog <file1 <file2
```

results in something similar to

```
cat file1 file2 | prog
```

Differences:

- It doesn't actually use `cat`, but it does create a new process to assist it.<sup>[2]</sup>
- All the file handles are opened up front rather than when needed.

---

1. ```
   % perl -e'exec "ls", "-l", "/proc/$$/fd"' <file1 <file2
   total 0
   lr-x------ 1 ikegami ikegami 64 Jun  4 16:16 0 -> 'pipe:[26665]'
   lrwx------ 1 ikegami ikegami 64 Jun  4 16:16 1 -> /dev/pts/0
   lrwx------ 1 ikegami ikegami 64 Jun  4 16:16 2 -> /dev/pts/0
   lr-x------ 1 ikegami ikegami 64 Jun  4 16:16 3 -> /proc/366/fd
   ```
2. ```
   % ps
     PID TTY          TIME CMD
      15 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
     338 pts/0    00:00:00 zsh
     372 pts/0    00:00:00 ps

   % perl -e'exec "ps"' <file1 <file2
     PID TTY          TIME CMD
      15 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
     338 pts/0    00:00:00 zsh
     373 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
     374 pts/0    00:00:00 zsh <defunct>    <- Helper
   ```