Redirect a function's stdout to out.log, stderr to err.log and both of them to combined.log, without running the function in a subshell
v=1

fun() {
    v=2
    echo out1
    >&2 echo err1
    echo out2
    >&2 echo err2
}

fun >out.log 2>err.log &>combined.log

The above does not work -- it only writes combined.log. out.log and err.log are empty. fun can't be run in a subshell, because it sets a global variable.
EDIT: The following almost does what I want, but stdout and stderr are not in the correct order inside combined.log.
{
    {
        fun >&3 > >(tee out.log)
    } 2>&1 2> >(tee err.log)
} >combined.log 3>&1

combined.log needs to look like the following:
out1
err1
out2
err2

EDIT2: Below are great answers, but none preserves the order inside combined.log. fun &>combined.log preserves the order. Would it somehow be possible to use something like that?

Can you modify fun to separate out the part that sets a global variable from the part that writes to stdout and stderr?

fun is just exemplary for any function (whether it has side effects like setting global variables or not). The functions I want to call in this way are blackbox/unknown but I want their side-effects to be preserved.

FYI, zsh behaves correctly, that it means it creates 3 files with correct contents. Maybe it's a bug in bash.

This should work:
fun 3> combined.log > >(tee out.log >&3) 2> >(tee err.log >&3)


But why is it needed? Is it expected behavior in bash?

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes. If you wonder why it works in zsh see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76401839/how-can-zsh-handle-multiple-redirections

@oguzismail Do you think that it's entirely impossible, to have combined.log in the correct order in addition to having a separate err.log and out.log in bash? Is there a stream redirect limitation in bash compared to zsh that makes this impossible?

@anick No idea.

See BashFAQ/106 for some ideas (especially "complex duplicate logging")

You can use named pipes for that:
v=1

fun() {
    v=2
    echo out1
    >&2 echo err1
    echo out2
    >&2 echo err2
}

mkfifo out.pipe
mkfifo err.pipe
mkfifo combined.pipe
trap 'rm -f out.pipe err.pipe combined.pipe' EXIT

tee <out.pipe out.log >combined.pipe &
stdout_pid=$!
tee <err.pipe err.log >combined.pipe &
stderr_pid=$!
cat <combined.pipe >combined.log &
combined_pid=$!

fun 1>out.pipe 2>err.pipe

wait $stdout_pid
wait $stderr_pid
wait $combined_pid

This sets up three pipes, one for stdout, one for stderr and one for the combined result. Two tee jobs read from the stdout and stderr pipes, and write their output both to the combined pipe and the corresponding log file. A cat job writes the combined pipe to the combined log.
By putting all these in background jobs, there's no need to create subshells.
I'm not sure this will always preserve entire lines; you might need to wrap the calls in stdbuf if you run into problems with that.
Note that it doesn't preserve ordering perfectly among stdout and stderr, because these are inherently unrelated streams.
It can probably be made more robust, but this is the basic idea.

Edit: we can shorten this recipe a bit using process substitution.
mkfifo combined.pipe
trap 'rm -f combined.pipe' EXIT

cat <combined.pipe >combined.log &
combined_pid=$!

fun 1> >(tee out.log >combined.pipe) 2> >(tee err.log >combined.pipe)

wait $combined_pid


Edit 2: If you shorten this even further, you end up at the oneliner by @oguzismail above. So I guess you just want to use that one.

Your ordering issues may be a buffering problem.
STDERR is typically unbuffered. STDOUT is usually buffered, and if you have them collecting to the same location they will often get out of order.
It's a little heavy handed, but if nothing else fixes it, maybe before calling your function try unbuffering STDOUT with something like
exec stdbuf -o0 "$0" "$@"
